# Mod Rewrite one variable or another on single rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Would it be possible to call one variable or another?

My type page gets either `tag` or `type` variables.

The code I have doesn't work, it only catches the first variable, `tag`.

How can I combine it into one or if not possible how do I make both work?

ex:

```
RewriteRule ^hen/egg/([^/\.]+)/?$ type.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hen/egg/([^/\.]+)/?$ type.php?type=$1 [L]
```

Comment: And the computer should telepathically guess which one the user meant?

Comment: I see the humor in that. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different virtual paths for them:

```
RewriteRule ^hen/tag/([^/\.]+)/?$ type.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hen/type/([^/\.]+)/?$ type.php?type=$1 [L]
```